# unrolling paper effect

Tags: animation

*A search for this question does yield results, but nothing seems to answer my immediate question*

I'm attempting to create an unrolling paper effect. https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOJLQwJKl5kPz_u32ITar5pH1fHledZwGiK-zAFVxAMh1iVTyR0ySe7qrJobsRBuA/photo/AF1QipNTPhU6WZPO_v3jr_KiiOGUayLtaYkls4HfZjPz?key=VHV2WER5bm5mUkhneHVpemNUeWRSaUZFZWFLMTJn
(ignore the video quality. no time to locate a decent screen capture program--I can do that later)

I've found a couple of tutorials, but the ones I can easily follow don't quite give the effect I need, and the ones that do what I want have no audio or are very tough to understand and move too quickly--one was from 2008.
This tutorial is the old one. It does what I want, but I can't get mine to act the same. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5TJEyHcB_E
This one is a good tutorial and easy enough to follow, but I don't want the wooden handles. It nearly does what I need. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aes92iyzFWA
And this guy also does basically what I want, but he moves too fast and doesn't explain anything. Difficult for me to follow at this time. He goes into drivers or something. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e428c7Jg96U

I've (hopefully) attached a quick clip (first link above) of what I'm trying to do; I've got the scene set up with an Archimedean spiral, and moving the spiral along the X axis the paper rolls up and unrolls.

I set the spiral location for key frame 1 and 100 and when animating the spiral moves accordingly, but the roll of paper either just sits in place, or mysteriously starts crumpling in place.

I'm likely missing something. Thanks in advance.

I'm running Blender version 2.81.16, Windows 10 64 bit

Please be simple with your answers, I'm still learning. Yes, I'm a noob ~ but hey, we all start at the bottom. ;)

Comment: Hi and welcome :) [gifs work well](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) and can be placed in your Q as images given they are under 2MB. This would make your Q much easier to follow. ( personally I use LiceCap) As for the related Q's you might have found, it's useful to reference them anyway in your Q to share your research :)

Comment: use cloth simulation with some settings and setup if you want a more dynamic paper animation, rather than using a simple deform modifier and a curve...

Comment: you can share your file if you want us to find out why it didn't work: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I don't understand how gifs will help here. I haven't reached the stage of my project to add images... Unless there's something in not understanding...

Comment: Thanks. Did the link to my video work? Also, not sure how add cloth. Just realized Q means question and you mean adding gifs in the question. Different forums use different terminology.  I'll put up my file later when I get back home.